# Making A Back Link Going To Same Page Left(Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

I'm using Kaminari pagination on a site, and when the user leaves the page and clicks the back link it goes back to the first page.

What I want is for the back link to go to the same page left. I know I should use a session variable for this, but I'm pretty new to Ruby On Rails so I'm not 100% positive on the syntax here.

Would love some help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to_function "Back", "history.go(-1);return true;" %>
```

I should add that it's a good practice to code links to pages as `<a>` tags rather than creating a form in your HTML for that purpose.

If you need to style the link to look like a button, do that in the CSS.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. That would work if the pagination was changing the url, but its not. Its just looping through a jQuery call that replaces entries on click.

Comment: Oh, now I see why you mentioned the Kaminari gem.

Comment: Yes, are you familiar with it?

Comment: I watched the RailsCasts episode, but I'm afraid it doesn't mention anything about that specifically.

Comment: Yeah, its a little more ahead of that. Are you familiar with setting a session with Rails?

Comment: I mean the RailsCasts episode about Kaminari, which is actually more complete than the official gem documentation on GitHub. Of course you could set your own session variable, but I thought you wanted to know if Kaminari is already doing the exact same thing to avoid redundancy.

Comment: I was wondering that too, but I'd just need to look at the syntax for the session in rails to get a good visual on it